# Why is my navbar hiding after clicking the toggle button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a website but it's having problems in mobile. The navbar shows when clicking the bars on top but the navbar hides when scrolling down a little on the mobile.

I assume there's a problem in my jQuery code. I added the resize function so when the browser is resized the left navbar shows.

This is frustrating, any help will be appreciated!

Check all the codes here for [demo](https://foxdesignstheme1.000webhostapp.com/parent/blogtime%20homedesign/index.html)

**HTML**

```
<div class="bars">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".bars").click(function(){ $(".regBox").slideToggle(); });

$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 768) { $(".regBox").hide(); }
    else{ $(".regBox").show(); }
});
```

Comment: Could you please specify the issue? When testing the demo you linked with screensize 375x667 (Iphone 6,7,8) the menu does not close on scroll. However, it also does not cover the entire screen and I can scroll the content behind it. Note: I tested on Firefox. It could be a browser issue you are experiencing?

Comment: Doesn't happen for me, what device and browser is it not working on?

Comment: I'm using LG G6 and tested it on chrome and opera, same problem happens with me when i click on the bars and then scroll a little or select the username text field the menu closes. Video demo https://vimeo.com/389583489